# Animating ImageView's tint property from color to color

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I want to animate one Image which is having black color drawable image. I want to animate its **`tint`** from one color to another in a circular fashion for all colors. Like starting from

> ->  Black -> Red -> Green -> Blue -> White

And then in reverse order. I should not stop. It should animate continuously.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have used ObjectAnimator with `tint` as the property. But it is not working

Answer (score 4):

Same problem, try "colorFilter" instead of "tint".

Comment: For now I have left it. I will check and update you shortly.